# sprintf to combine char arrays

Tags: c, arrays, printf

I have a char array and some variables and I want to use sprintf to combine them.

the variables are defined as such:

```
uint8_t var1;
char name1[20];
char textout1[40];
```

at different points of the program I use strcpy to fill name1.

```
strcpy(name1, "hello");
```

var1 also gets a value assigned

```
var1 = 5;
```

Then I want to combine them into a char array using sprintf.

```
sprintf(textout1, "%s %u", name1, var1);
```

If I now print textout1, I get

```
 5
```

The string/char array is missing. Can anyone figure out why this is?
Printing the name1 array seperately gives me the expected "hello", so strlcpy works fine.

A minimal code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t var1;
char name1[20];
char textout1[40];


int main() {
   strcpy(name1, "hello");
   var1 = 5;
   sprintf(textout1, "%s %u", name1, var1);
   printf(textout1);
   printf(name1);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcpy` null-terminates automatically. What's the point of `strlcpy` again?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Look at [this](https://www.ideone.com/LAqK8H). I replaced the non standard `strlcpy` with `strcpy`, which shouldn't change anything. The problem is probably somewhere in the code you didn't show.

Comment: from what I read, strcpy doesn't null-terminate but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: @C.Winters add `#include <string.h>` and try again. Compile with warnings enabled.

Comment: As pointed by @Jabberwocky you have include missing. Also, use `strncpy` instead of `strlcpy` and you will have it working: https://ideone.com/j1oWRz

Comment: @JorgeBellón Don't use `strncpy`, it does not what you think it does.

Comment: @C.Winters what are your platform/OS/IDE/compiler?

Comment: It was just a quick and dirty ammend. I know what it does and it's just a matter of setting the right size and initializing the array properly: `strncpy(name1, "hello", sizeof(name1)-1)`

Comment: @JorgeBellón OK, so you _are_ aware that `strncpy` may leave you with a non NUL terminated char array.

Comment: @C.Winters The code you posted prints out `hello 5hello` on a single line, which is exactly what one would expect of this code. Did you expect something else ? Do you actually have a different problem that this minimal example does not show ?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing either a newline at the end of your string or a fflush(stdout).

printf() will buffer the passed strings until it encounters a newline character. If you want to see what you print you have to add a

```
fflush(stdout);
```

at the end of your program.